# Entity Framework Include column from child table

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-one

I have two tables 
**User{UserId, Name, UserTypeId, Email}** 
and 
**UserType{UserTypeId,Value}**
One to One relationship.
Is there a way to Map them into Single Entity like
**Class User{UserId, Name, UserType, Email}** where **UserType** is a string which needs to get value from **UserType.Value** column

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use LINQ on the results:

```
var DerivedUsers =
    from User in Users
    join Type in UserType on User.UserTypeId equals Type.UserTypeId
    select new { UserId = User.UserId, Name = User.Name, UserType= Type.Value, Email = User.Email };
```

This is the easiest way.
Otherwise, according to [this Microsoft blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2009/03/23/mapping-two-tables-to-one-entity-in-the-entity-framework/),

> There are actually two main options;
>
> 1. Do the mapping in the Entity Framework, which requires that both tables must share the same primary key. Therefore if you have
>      Customer and CustomerAddress tables (with a 1:1 relationship) the
>      CustomerId must be the primary key on the CustomerAddress table.
> 2. Do the mapping in the database, using an updatable View that you manually map into the Entity Framework’s model. Rick has a post
>      about how you might do this here.

But I guess option 1. is out of the window, since I don't think your tables share the primary key, and option 2. is not what you're asking, since it requires work on the database, while you are asking for a mapping.

Answer (score 0):

If your relationship is properly designed, for example:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
context.Users
    .Select(u => new UserViewModel {
        UserId = u.UserId,
        UserName = u.Name,
        UserEmail = u.Email,
        UserType = u.UserType.Value
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Perhaps you can add what makes it different from my solution (i.e. he won't have an anonymous type) and/or highlight what's a ViewModel. To help him more, that's it.

Comment: I implied from her or his question that there is a need to map from 2 classes to 1. Label it a ViewModel, DTO or whatever. A question that terse is probably going to involve some exchange. Personally, I would only [resort to a JOIN](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/) if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks, interesting article. I thought it was because of performance reasons; actually it seems because of readability. Personally I still feel more comfortable with "SQL-like" queries, maybe because I'm just more used to it. But navigation properties do look neat.